# call function with two string parameters in Common-LISP Programming

Tags: syntax, common-lisp

I created a function which gets two string parameters. The function simply adds each string length. below is a code.

```
(defun add_twostring_length (mystr1 mystr2)
(+ (length mystr1) (length mystr2))
)
```

When I call `add_twostring_length` function like this,

> (add_twostring_length "cpp" "lisp")

output is correct. **7**

But, when I call the same function in the manner of using comma,

> (add_twostring_length "cpp", "lisp")

I got an error message.

> Error: Comma not inside a backquote.
>
> [condition type: READER-ERROR]

I want to call function in the manner of `(add_twostring_length "cpp", "lisp")`.

What is the wrong with the code?

[picture showing error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLPze.jpg)

Comment: commas are for escaping expressions in backquotes.  You have no backquote, so there's nothing to esacpe.

Comment: Could you give me some hints?
fist, I tryed `(defun add_twostring_length '(mystr1,(mystr2))
(+ (length mystr1) (length mystr2))
)`
but this also doesn't work.

Second, I tryed `(defun add_twostring_length '((mystr1) (mystr2))
(+ (length mystr1) (length mystr2))
)`
It also doesn't work.

could you give me some hints? @ChrisDodd

Comment: @박주현 You're not supposed to use commas for separating arguments in Lisp. Arguments are always separated by spaces, just like you did first. Using a comma there is a syntax error, and won't work.

Comment: You might be confusing with Clojure, which allows commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is possible, but I will strongly advice **against** using it:

```
(set-macro-character #\,
                     #'(lambda (stream char)
                         (read stream t nil t)))
```

The above code creates the so called "read macro". At read-time common lisp will find all occurrences of `,` and ignore them. This makes possible calling functions like so:

```
(+ 1, 2, 3) ; => 6
```

However this will break escaping in templates:

```
`(1 2 ,(+ 3 4)) ; => (1 2 (+ 3 4))
```

Perhaps it is possible to make the read macro more intelligent, but I don't want to delve deeper into this, because I don't like the idea. Sorry.

Comment: I don't understand your idea. should I replace char (in your suggested code) with add_twostring_length call?

Comment: @박주현 (1) The idea is to change the **Lisp Reader**: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_a.htm. The expression changes the current **readtable** so that commas are just like whitespace. (2) No, you are supposed to execute the first snippet (3) You still didn't say **why** you want that feature. This is important because your request is unreasonable.

Comment: It really is a waste of time writing those extra `,` that don't need to be there and that wlll eventually give you bugs that will haunt you in your sleep. If you in a macro accidentally do `\`(/ a b ,(+ 5 ,d)`. Say the bug is that it's the inner list was accidentally unquoted and that you won't find the bug if you test with numeric literals. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

You might as well ask "why can't I call the function without parentheses?"  In lisp, you call functions as an sexpr with the function in the car and the arguments in the cdr.  There are no commas involved -- that's the syntax of lisp.